# ¿Cómo corregir el error Internal error: User control doesn't have a Design Render?

Tags: genexus, usercontrol

Agrego el UC Uploadify, pero no se por que no me lo reconoce.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias aclarar muchisimo mas tu pregunta.. de que es esa imagen? que es usercontrol? que lenguaje? que ide? agregas que cosa a donde? vos esperas que alguien sepa, pero tenes que ayudar a todos a entender que te pasa para poder guiarte...

Comment: Hola, PERDON, la verdad entre al foro por un link que entendí era de Genexus. Soy nuevo con la herramienta Genexus. Estoy levantando una Base de Conocimiento. Los User Control, son controles que pueden insertarse en el form de cualquier objeto web de GeneXus. Sirven para enriquecer el aspecto y funcionalidad de nuestras aplicaciones. En mi caso agregue el que indica en el error "Uploadify" pero en el Form no lo instala o reconoce. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola.. bienvenido.. pero para empezar, esto no es un foro... y particularmente, no es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas de una herramienta, es de todas. Te recomendaria que sigas los links que te pase, y luego, que si tenes que agregar mas informacion a tu pregunta, lo hagas usando el boton [edit] debajo de la misma. Agrega las etiquetas correspondientes a la pregunta, a ver si alguien puede ayudarte.

Comment: OK, muchas gracias, disculpa las molestias. Saludos

Comment: No es ninguna molestia, para nada! solo dedicale un rato a ajustar tu pregunta, y si alguien puede ayudarte con gusto lo hara...

Comment: ¿De qué manera instalaste el UC? Si lo hiciste manualmente, ¿ corriste el comando : <GX_Installation_Path>\GeneXus /install ? https://tinyurl.com/ycy8r2e4